# Xamarin Converter Not Found With Proper Namespace & Name Reference in XML

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-code, xamarin.android

I created a simple bool converter that inverts the value of a bool.

```
namespace MyApp.Helpers
{
    public class BoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
            }

            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("BoolConverter does not support convert back");
        }
    }
```

I have saved this file and it exists in my directory with the same name:

[image: file in assembly]

However when I try to reference this inside of my xml code it can never find it:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Login.LoginScreen"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Helpers;assembly=MyApp">
        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <converters:BoolConverter x:Key="BoolConverter" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
```

The line `<converters:BoolConverter x:Key="BoolConverter" />` errors out with

> The type 'converters:BoolConverter' was not found. Verify that you are
>   not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies
>   have been built. (MyApp) IntelliSense

I have done a clean as well.

Do you know why it cannot find my converter?

[image]

Comment: Is it just an IntelliSense warning or does it fail during compile/runtime? i.e. IntelliSense is far from perfect, especially when it comes to external references.

Comment: You are correct. Cleaning did not work, but when I closed Visual Studio Code and then re-opened it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) said, it is just an IntelliSense warning. You can clean the solution or just close and re-open Visual Studio.